# Adjust size of popup balloon with embedded image to fit window size in KML file on Google Earth

Tags: image, popup, kml

Given is a `KML` file with a single placemark and an on-click popup ballon which can be opened in GoogleEarth. This balloon contains an image which is larger than what fits on the average screen. I would like the popup balloon to be dynamically sized to (almost) make use of the full screen, independent of the physical screen size or resolution. Inside this popup, the image should be scaled accordingly to be fully visible without scroll bars.

Current situation:
[image: Current situation]

Desired situation:
[image: Desired situation]

Is this feasible somehow? I couldn't figure out any HTML/CSS combination yet to make it work.

This is the `KML` source for the upper screenshot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>Two large images stacked vertically and adjusted to screen size in popup balloon</name>
        <Style id="abc123">
            <IconStyle>
                <color>000000</color>
                <scale>0.50</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/shaded_dot.png</href>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>0</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Some placemark</name>
            <styleUrl>#abc123</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>4.732276,52.604905</coordinates>
            </Point>
            <description><![CDATA[<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494256997604-768d1f608cac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" />]]></description>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer indicated, you can size an image in a balloon using basic HTML tools. You can also do that dynamically using javascript to resize the image.  But you seem to be asking if you can customize the image and balloon size based on the screen size, and unfortunately I don't  know of any way for the HTML and Javascript in the balloon to know what the current screen size is, so I don't think it's possible to dynamically expand the image to fill the screen.

One possible alternative might be to have a smaller (thumbnail?) image in the balloon that links to the full-size image. That way users could click the image and open it in Earth's internal browser window, which automatically sizes to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The description in a Placemark can have HTML so one solution is by setting the height and width attributes in the `<img>` tag and another approach is adding a `<div>` tag with a width to control the width.

The screenshot below illustrates an image in a popup when setting a custom width.

[image: image with custom width in Google Earth Pro]

KML Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>Two large images stacked vertically and adjusted to screen size in popup balloon</name>
        <Style id="abc123">
            <IconStyle>
                <color>000000</color>
                <scale>0.50</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/shaded_dot.png</href>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>0</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Some placemark</name>
            <styleUrl>#abc123</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>4.732276,52.604905</coordinates>
            </Point>
            <description><![CDATA[
                <img width="600" height="400"
                   src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg"/>
                ]]>
            </description>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Second approach is adding a `<div>` tag width a width.

```
<description><![CDATA[
<div style="width:624px;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg"/>
</div>
]]></description>
```